# Mac Cannot unmount Disk Images that are mounted from Samba Shares

Tags: freebsd, samba, macintosh, smb

I am on a Mac OS 12.6.8.

I have gotten Samba to work great with TimeMachine and general sharing of directories off the server which is running FreeBSD 13.2 with Samba Version 4.16.10.

The one issue I am seeing is that when I have a Mac Disk Image mounted from a Samba share it will not unmount unless I hit the force eject option.

When I run ‘sudo smbstatus’ on the server I see the mounted disk image is locked:

```
Pid          User(ID)   DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
25419        1001       DENY_NONE  0x20087     RDWR       NONE             /usr/home/alex   test.dmg   Sun Jul 30 13:36:02 2023
25419        1001       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /usr/home/alex   .   Sun Jul 30 13:36:16 2023
```

I don’t have any issues with TimeMachine which in theory mounts a disk image from the share and then unmounts it cleanly when it is done with it. Only when I mount a disk image from my home directory. I also tried to make a specific entry in smb.conf to a specific directory with the disk image and saw the same behavior. My conf file is below. Let me know if any other info is needed:

```
# We want Samba to only log to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd}.
# Append syslog@1 if you want important messages to be sent to syslog too.
 logging = file

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
#   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
allow insecure wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[TimeMachineLB]
# Load in modules (order is critical!)
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
fruit:time machine = yes
fruit:time machine max size = 350G
comment = Time Machine Backup
path = /storage/TimeMachineLB
available = yes
valid users = alex
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
writable = yes

[TimeMachine2]
# Load in modules (order is critical!)
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
fruit:time machine = yes
fruit:time machine max size = 300G
comment = Time Machine Backup Nat
path = /storage/TimeMachine2
available = yes
valid users = natalie
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
writable = yes

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
valid users = %S
read only = No
create mask = 0700
directory mask = 0700
browseable = yes
#veto files = /*.*/
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
```

Regards,

Alex

Comment: Can you add exactly what your `mount` looks like? Also, have you checked the output of `fstat`, or whether Spotlight is trying to index the Samba volume?